# is a SOQL subquery with a junction object possible?

Tags: soql, junction-object, opportunitycontactrole

I am trying to access Contact information from a Opportunity object across a OpportunityContactRole. Does SOQL support this?

Comment: welcome to SFSE - please see [ask] for tips on getting the most from the community

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

> Select Id,Name,(select Id,ContactId,Contact.Name from
>   OpportunityContactRoles) from Opportunity

Answer (score 0):

For this case I would create a function that can give me the contacts related to the Opportunity, like

This function will return list of unique(based on Id) contacts related to that Opportunity

```
private Map<Id, Contact> getRelatedContacts(String oppId) {

    Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();

    //Add all Contact fields as per requirement
    for(OpportunityContactRoles oppConRole : [SELECT Id,ContactId,Contact.Name, Contact.Email 
                                                FROM OpportunityContactRoles
                                                WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId]) {
        if(!contactMap.containsKey(oppConRole.ContactId)) {
            contactMap.put(oppConRole.ContactId, new Contact(Name = oppConRole.Contact.Name,
                                                             Email = oppConRole.Contact.Email));
        }
    }

    return contactMap;

}
```